# Draw transparency of image on BufferStrategy

Tags: java

Good day,

I tried to draw a picture on a `BufferStrategy` with its `Graphics`. The picture has a transparent background and if I draw it on the screen the transparent areas change to black.

[image: Blue example]

The blue thing is the image I want to draw but without the black parts (in the original picture they are not there).

That is how I draw the picture:

```
BufferedImage image = loadImage(path);

g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);

public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path));

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics g = image.createGraphics();

        icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
        g.dispose();

        return image;

}
```

Comment: Explain your question in detail with source code and also provide image what you want as a result for a good solution.

Comment: @Programmer I updated it :)

Comment: your image has no alpha channel. use BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGBA instead

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Andreas is correct but is should be `ARGB` rather than `RGBA`.

To do this just change `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` in this line:

`BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);`

To `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`:

`BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);`

---

Edit in response to your comment, here is the complete answer:

In addition to creating a BufferedImage as `TYPE_INT_ARGB` you also need to apply the AlphaComposite `SRC_OVER` to your buffered image using Graphics2D like this:

```
public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path)
{
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(path);

    //using TYPE_INT_ARGB
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);    

    //changed to G2D change here
    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
    //get alpha
    AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER);  
    //set alpha
    g2d.setComposite(ac);

    icon.paintIcon(null, g2d, 0, 0);
    g2d.dispose();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but there was no change, still black background -.-

Comment: You also need to apply the AlphaComposite `SRC_OVER` to your buffered image using Graphics2D. See my edit above with working code.